# C# format string date

Tags: c#, string

I have a string in the following format

> 19/11/2012 15:40:15

I would like to convert this to UTC format but still keep it as a string. e.g:

> 2012-11-19T15:40:15.000000+00:00

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DateTimeOffset.Parse` and convert it to `UTC` and then back to `String` as below:

```
string date= "19/11/2012 15:40:15";
string newUTCdate=Convert.ToString(DateTimeOffset.Parse(date).UtcDateTime);
```